# How $P[X=x]= \frac2{3^x}$ can give an even value for $x =1,2,3,\dots$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, elementary-probability

I have a question that says “Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability function $P[X=x] = \frac2{3^x}$ for $x = 1,2,3,\dots$ What is the probability that $X$ is even?  The thing is I don’t understand how this function can give $2,4,6,8$ etc..... if $x$ is from the natural numbers.

Comment: the probability that $X$ is 2 is $P(X=2)$. The probability that $X$ is 2 or 4 is $P(X=2) + P(X=4)$. The probability that $X$ is even is...

Answer (score 2):

> "What is the probability that $X$ is even?"

That is the question!

Not: "for what $x$ is the probability $P(X=x)$ even?"

Comment: Ahh thank you! Your answer pinpointed what I was misunderstanding :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Because even numbers such as $2,4,6$ are natural number.

For example, even though the dice can gives value from $1$ to $6$, we can ask for the probability that it is even itsn't it.

To solve the problem, compute

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^{2x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Probability of $X$ being even implies:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(X=2n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3^{2n}}=2\cdot \frac{\frac19}{1-\frac19}=\frac14.$$